# Basic JSON With PHP

Tags: php, json

I have some Data like this in PHP:

```
NumberOfPeople.php
<?php
$numberOfPeople = 5;
?>
```

How do I convert that variable into a JSON Object and then output it into an HTML file.

Something like this:

```
RandomHTMLFile.html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var NumberOfPeople = JSON VARIABLE FROM THE PHP FILE
</script>
```

This is the type of thing JSON is for right?

Notice that the Output file is in an HTML file and not a PHP File, so it has to be completely Javascript based.

Also the HTML file will be on a different server than the PHP file.

Comment: Are you going to have more complex variables?  A number like that doesn't need to be json encoded.  Just do `var NumberOfPeople = <?php echo $numberOfPeople ?>;`

Comment: I'm trying to pass that data into an HTML file via Javascript, so I think it has to be encoded since the HTML file can't parse PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it into a PHP array and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json-encode) function

```
$jsonArray = array('numberOfPeople' => 5); //Now the value will be accessible under `numberOfPeople` json index
$json = json_encode($jsonArray);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Should your `$numberOfPeople` key actually be a variable?

Comment: @jprofitt, I am not sure, what kind of index, he is going to use.

Comment: But with [what you have](http://codepad.org/hlfLhcCj), it's going to be an array with the key that is the same as the value. If you don't know what the value is in the first place, then you're going to have to do magic to get it.

Comment: What would I put in the HTML file?

Comment: @Talon, Can you tell me, how are you planning to get the json data in the HTML file at first place?

Comment: Ajax, or whatever way is best, I would prefer not to use Jquery or any library.  Also the HTML file will be on a different server than the PHP file.

Comment: @Talon, Cross Domain, JSON requests are not possible. If have to use JSONP for it.

Answer (score 1):

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) is the main thing you'll need. Just beware of UTF-8 encoding requirements. Use [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8-encode) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To access a json output generated at the server side from a static html page, you may use `jquery`'s built-in `$.getJSON` function.

```
RandomHTMLFile.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var NumberOfPeople;
  $.getJSON('NumberOfPeople.php',{},function(response){ 
     NumberOfPeople = response;
  });
</script>
```

and at the server side you need to convert the variable to json with php's `json_encode` function:

```
NumberOfPeople.php
<?php
$numberOfPeople = 5;
echo json_encode($numberOfPeople);
?>
```

Of course you may consider generating the html page using the pre-calculated variables. It is possible to output html with php and serve it as if they're requested like static html pages. You may want to read about `mod_rewrite` to achieve this.

Comment: I'm trying to make this variable accessible to people as a Javascript code snippet they can include anywhere, which is why I can't use mod_rewrite or anything like that.  I'll give this code a shot, it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Set the headers to json instead and then fetch it with javascript.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Comment: How do you fetch it with Javascript? That's what I don't know how to do.

Comment: ajax. either with vanilla javascript or a framework such as jquery. There are tonnes of tutorials out there.

Comment: Do you know if it's even possible if the HTML file is on a different server than the PHP file?

Comment: you would need to scrap the other website, with the owners permission of course.  The best way to get the value would be to use curl and DomDocument to get the value.  javascript does not allow for doing cross site requests, unless its jsonp format.

Answer (score 0):

**NumberOfPeople.php**

```
<?php
$data['NumberOfPeople'] = 5;
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**RandomHTMLFile.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var NumberOfPeople;
      $.getJSON('NumberOfPeople.php',function(data){ 
         var NumberOfPeople = data.NumberOfPeople;
      });
    </script>
```